# Simulating PSoC 5LP

Tags: simulation, psoc, proteus

I am working on extracting strain gauge values mounted on my ATV (front suspension) with the help of a 20 bit ADC of PSoC 5LP. Before that, I would like to simulate it. So could you please suggest an appropriate simulator? I have tried it on proteus but seems like proteus does not support cypress chips.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution: It is to upgrade the `Proteus Software (Proteus 3.10)`.Here, libraries are provided from the internet so no need to manually search for them.
Thank you :)